# How should I add redis when identityServer4 receive the token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Now, I am using the IdentityServer4 right now to protect my API, I was planning to use Redis to save the token until it's expired. I want to use Redis to check if the token is validated and activated when identityServer4 receive the token from the discovery endpoint. However, I have not idea where to start and which interface should I modify. Any help will be appreciated. Also, I would like to know more about how the discovery point work when the IS4 get the token send from protected API.

I am trying to modify the ITokenValidator, but seemingly it is not related to the token validation.

The right process will be after the IdentityServer receives the token from API, it will compare the token with the record in Redis and tell the protected API the authentication result.

Comment: do you use jwt or reference tokens? do you know the difference? tokens of the first type do not suppose idp-side validation. what is your expectation from redis? I could just provide the link, but I'm not sure you are sure what you are doing. and finally, discovery is just a set of links and settings. for token validation IdSrv provides introspection endpoint.

Comment: No, I am using the Jwt token right now. And it comes out that I was in the wrong direction yesterday about how the token is validated. Since the default token type in identity Server4 is Jwt, not reference token. Actually, I was thinking of using the Redis as cache to store the token and the config information(e.g Api resource, client information). Also after user changes the password or is deleted, I can disable the token even it's not expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IdentityServer4.Contrib.RedisStore](https://github.com/AliBazzi/IdentityServer4.Contrib.RedisStore). It brings two features: caching capabilities (IdSrv has some out of the box, and probably that would be enough) and `IPersistedGrantStore` implementation. That store is the place where Identity server places reference and refresh tokens.